# Will WebdriverIO work with Selenium 3.X

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

I've just started learning WebdriverIO So I have quick question. On their github repository I have seen older version of chrome & firefox. So will WebdriverIO work with updated Chrome version e.g 62.x or Firefox with 47.x ?

Also will it work with selenium 3.x ?? I have heard that its only has a support for selenium version 2.x??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between **Selenium 2** & **Selenium 3** is that they renounced the old **[Selenium RC](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/)** architecture and now they are solely implementing the **[Webdriver W3C Standard](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html)**, which I highly recommend you read.

Renouncing *Selenium RC* means that there is no backwards compatibility between *Selenium 1* and *3*, *Selenium 2* being a middle way to ease the migration to the new **Webdriver API** implementation.

You should have absolutely no problem running with **Selenium 3.x**.

---

That being said, I am speaking out of experience (going for second year with a WebdriverIO-based framework). I never had any **major** problems with WebdriverIO and the main issues you'll encounter are the following:

- **driver teams** (**[gheckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)**, **[chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)**, etc) not implementing the Webdriver standard correctly (just file a BUG, or keep a lookout for already opened issues related to your problem on their respective **GitHub Issues** page);
- **major browsers** having switched to a more aggressive release schedule will sometimes push new features not tackled by the equivalent **driver**, thus by updating, you might end up with failing checks;
- **deprecation** and/or **lacking/limited functionality:** the [guys](https://www.w3.org/testing/browser/) working on **WebDriver** will cut and add features in accordance with how they see the progression of web-apps automation, so you will always have to switch to some new methods/approaches/best-practices every now & then.

**!!! Note:** all this free-software (**Selenium**, **WebdriverIO**, etc.) you're enjoying is mostly produced by **a
   handful of people** that sacrifice their free/spare time to deliver it. It's not their **job** to deliver BUG-fixes and deploy like Google does with Chrome (*every six weeks*).

So have patience & if you can, **contribute! :)**